# Word Macro to create a pie chart from numerous tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document, full of tables. The first row in each table is the title, using a modified "Heading 1" style, and there is also an Category field, using a modified heading 4 style.

I would like to write a macro that will group each table by category, and create a chart showing the distributions.

Is this possible, and if so, where could I find a reference on how to start?

I'm not a VBA programmer, but I have a reasonable grasp of programming languages and hoping I can hack something together if I can find the right references and if it is even possible..

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little too open but maybe something like this can help

```
'Option Explicit

Sub CreatePie()

    Dim shReport As Worksheet
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim oChart  As Shape
    Dim arrSources As Variant

    ' Remove the report sheet, this is just to remove the testng sheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Report").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Get all the srouces. Asuming that they all start in Range("A")
    arrSources = GetSources

    Set shReport = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    shReport.Name = "Report"
    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlConsolidation, arrSources)
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable("Report!R1C1")
    Set oChart = shReport.Shapes.AddChart2(, xlPie)
    oChart.Chart.SetSourceData pt.TableRange1

End Sub

' Function to get all the ranges to be consolitidated.
Function GetSources() As Variant

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ret() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim ret(Sheets.Count - 1)

    ' Fill all the ranges
    For i = 0 To Sheets.Count - 1
        Set sh = Sheets(i + 1)
        Set rng = sh.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

        ret(i) = Array(sh.Name & "!" & rng.Address(True, True, xlR1C1), "Item" & i + 1)
    Next i

    Var = Array(Array("Sheet1!R1C1:R5C2", "Item1"), Array("Sheet2!R1C1:R5C2", "Item2"), Array("Sheet3!R1C1:R5C2", "Item3"))

    ' Return the value
    GetSources = ret

End Function
```

[Here is my sample file.](http://www.filedropper.com/samplepie)

Hope this helps :)